# KeyError using apply function

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with the following columns, and I'm simply trying to add a new column by transforming an existing one. I don't understand why I get this error, especially given is that the data frame is fine and I can `groupby` on `Zip` without any index problems.

```
print(df.columns)

# Index(['First Col', 'Year', 'Submitted', 'Allowed', 'Provided', 'X', 'Zip'],
# dtype='object')

print(df['Zip'])

# 0       10523
# 1       11803
# 2       22939
# 3       21742
# 4       21801
# 5       21804
# ...

df['NEW'] = df.apply(lambda row: cool_fn(row['Zip']))
KeyError: ('Zip', 'occurred at index First Col')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For processing per rows is necessary add `axis=1` to [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['NEW'] = df.apply(lambda row: cool_fn(row['Zip']), axis=1)
```

Or use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), then lambda should be omit:

```
df['NEW'] = df['Zip'].apply(cool_fn)
```